# Google Tag Manager Publish Button Not Showing

Tags: google-analytics

I've recently started to use Google Tag Manager and I have read/edit access to the container, created a tag with accompanying rules, and saved the version. Next, I went to the versions menu, clicked on the tag version I wanted to publish, and it takes me to a page with that tag's information. On the right side of the page, there should be a Publish and Preview button available based on what I've seen in their video and from what I read in other support forums. For me, there is only a Preview button. I went ahead and clicked on it and went through the site preview and debugging options, but no publish button even after I verified everything was fine and came back. I reloaded the page, still nothing. Added more tags and saved their versions, can't publish any of them either as the button still isn't there. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks like you do not have enough permissions to publish containers.
GTM account/containers have 3 levels of access:

1. View only
2. View and Edit only
3. View, Edit, Delete, and Publish

Ask webmaster to add you access level "View, Edit, Delete, and Publish".

---

[image]